# HTTP Rest URL considering + as concatination

Tags: rest-api, apexrest

I'm trying to send http request as below-

```
/services/apexrest/ContactSearch?contactNumber=+(734)-122345&VIPCheck=false
```

I'm receiving contactnumber as (734)-122345. But i'm expecting +(734)-122345. Please help!

Answer (score 3):

This is because you are working with a URL and `+` is the equivalent of a space. You can either pass `%2B` (encoded input for `+`, see [HTML URL Encoding Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.ASP)) or append the `+` to your bind variable before querying the SF DB on your custom rest class i.e `ContactSearch`.

```
/services/apexrest/ContactSearch?contactNumber=%2B(734)-122345&VIPCheck=false
```

Comment: Most languages also have a [encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) or equivalent to do this automatically. If available, it is recommended to use a library function instead of "doing it yourself."